# Slow checkbox updating in treepanel grid

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid, treepanel

Here is what I am doing to update all the child nodes in treegrid. Updating child nodes result in refreshing view of each row which seems to slow down updating process of checking checkbox.

I have tried using ext.suspendLayout, component.suspendlayout, component.suspendEvents but no gain in performance.There are around 80 childnodes that need to be checkd when parent node is checked.It takes around 4 seconds to get this done.

[HTML]

```
//code for checkbox that is recursively updated.
return Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Checkbox", {
            checked: checked,
            record: record,
            name: "Enabled",
            fieldCls: record.data.nodeLevel != 2 ? (checked == 1 ? "checkBlue" : (checked == 2 ? "checkBlack" : '')) : "",
            hideable: false,
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            name: "TreeCheckStatus",




            handler: function (checkbox, checked) {





                page.gridPanel.suspendEvents();

                Ext.defer(function () { record.set("TreeCheckStatus", getTriStatevalue(record)); }, 1);

//recursive function to update all child notes records
                updateAllChild(record, getTriStatevalue(record));

                page.gridPanel.resumeEvents(true);

            }
        });


    }




    //recursive method to update all the nodes
      function updateAllChild(record, value) {


        if (record.hasChildNodes()) {
            // page.gridPanel.suspendLayouts();
            var childParentStatus = true;
            Ext.each(record.childNodes, function (rec) {
                rec.beginEdit();






                rec.set("TreeCheckStatus", value);

                updateAllChild(rec, value);


                rec.endEdit();

            });


        }



    }[/HTML]![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Have you tried to suspend events on `TreeStore`?

Comment: yes  tried that also. It does not improve performance

Comment: Updating the store alone is never a performance problem as it is only in-memory operation. The bottleneck is always manipulating DOM that results from data changes in the store as view listens to store events. Therefore I still think that view, and thus DOM, is updated on each checked change. No custom listener? Did the suspendEvents really stopped the view updates?